# странное поведение js

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, битрикс

Делаю календарь (принцип - листаем слайды по 7 дней), ниже пока всё что я уже сделал, но консоль вдруг мне стала выдавать ошибку - `Uncaught ReferenceError: dateup is not defined` , самое главное(!) - её причина это вот этот блок кода -

```
$(".all-month .items-date:last-child").each(function () {
                    if($(this).find(".cube:last").html()<10){
                        $(this).remove();
                    }
                });
```

если его убрать, ошибка исчезнет, но как он связан с тем что переменная просто пропадает я не могу понять.
 Ещё что я не могу понять, это то что переменная `toggle_month` после работы функции не меняется, хоть и является глобальной (проверял на отдельной примитивной функции - в отдельном файле переменная меняется, а в том где обработчик календаря - нет, то есть вы, скорее всего, эту проблему просто не сможете воспроизвести), есть хотя бы догадки почему так происходит?

```
function add_month_time(a, month, nextprev) {

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: document.getElementById('calendar_component_path').value + "/ajax.php",
        data: {ajax_time: true, month: month, sessid: BX.bitrix_sessid()},
        cache: false,
        dataType: 'html',
        beforeSend: function(){
            renderLoader(a, month, nextprev);
        },
        timeout: 8000,
        success: function (html) {

            // данные пришли корректно
            if(html){
                removeLoader();
                removeError();

                if (nextprev == "next") {$(".gooajax").append(html);}
                if (nextprev == "prev") {$(".gooajax").prepend(html);}
                //костыль для удаления страницы без содержимого
                $(".all-month .items-date:last-child").each(function () {
                    if ($(this).html() == "")$(this).remove();
                });
                //костыль для определения есть ли в видимой неделе начало следующей
                $(".all-month .items-date:last-child").each(function () {
                    if($(this).find(".cube:last").html()<10){
                        $(this).remove();
                    }
                });

                $(".all-month").each(function () {
                    $(this).find(".items-date:last").addClass("end-week");
                });

                var week_today = $("#today").parent().parent();
                if (a == 1) {
                    week_today.show();
                    week_today.parent().show();
                }

                ///вызывается 1 раз при формировании, если попали на крайнюю неделю - подгружаем следующую
                if (a) {

                    //если мы на последней неделе сразу аяксим следующую
                    if (week_today.hasClass("end-week")) {
                        $(".control-items-date.next").html("Следующий месяц");
                        toggle_month = "next";
                        console.log(toggle_month);
                        if (!(parseFloat($(".all-month:visible").data("month")) < parseFloat(dateup))) {
                            dateup = parseFloat(dateup) + 1;
                            if (dateup < 10)dateup = "0" + dateup;
                            add_month_time(0, dateup, "next");
                        }
                    }

                    //если мы на первой неделе сразу аяксим предыдущую
                    if (week_today.hasClass("start-week")) {

                        $(".control-items-date.prev").html("Предыдущий месяц");

                        toggle_month = "prev";

                        if (!(parseFloat($(".all-month:visible").data("month")) > parseFloat(datedown))) {
                            datedown = parseFloat(datedown) - 1;
                            if (datedown < 10)datedown = "0" + datedown;
                            add_month_time(0, datedown, "prev");
                        }
                    }
                }//if(a)

            }else{
                removeLoader();
                renderError(a, month, nextprev);
            }
        }//success end
    });//ajax end
}//function end

BX.ready(function() {

    var dateup = $("#cur_date").val();
    var datedown = $("#cur_date").val();
    var bool = false;
    var toggle_month = 0;
    var slide_month;


    var current_month;
    var control_next = $(".control-items-date.next");
    var control_prev = $(".control-items-date.prev");

    add_month_time(1, dateup, "next");
    ...
```

и так выглядит **DOM** структура календаря:

```
    <div class="all-month" data-month="09" style="display: block;">//контейнер для месяца
       <div class="month fs22 regular">Сентябрь</div>//имя месяца
          <div class="items-date start-week">//слайд с 7 днями недели
             <div class="relative item fs14 regular">//сам день
             <div class="cube medium fs13">29</div> 
             <div class="day regular fs14">Понедельник</div>
             <div class="c"></div>
             <span class="l fs22 regular gray_text">с 09:00 до 19:00</span>
          </div>
...
```

Comment: Изменение toggle_month проверяете после вызова `add_month_time` внутри `BX.ready`?

Comment: да, в обработчике onclick, эта переменная должна иметь значение при котором слайд перелиснется, но он этого не делает. начинает работать только после кликанья туда-сюда(в обработчике задаются нужные значения и все начинает работать)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

как всегда, стоило только задать вопрос - решение нашлось само. соль в том что я объявляю переменные внутри функции `BX.ready(function() {` ключевое слово - функции, и все что внутри - локально, поэтому переменные и не менялись при вызове других функций которые их должны менять, поэтому всё и работало в отдельном файле